# How can I build for iphone simulator when using BluetoothManager.framework?

Tags: iphone, ios, linker, bluetooth

I dragged the folder BluetoothManager.framework from finder into the Frameworks group in project navigator. It builds successfully for device, but can't find the framework when I build for simulator. I understand that simulator doesn't support bluetooth, but I need to have it buildable for simulator, so that other people can continue testing their part in simulator. How can I exclude the framework from linking when building for simulator? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weaklink the library, add exclude any bluetooth code with compiler directives :

```
#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR 
    //Bluetooth code 
#endif
```

Comment: I configured out to use _other linker flags_ in _build settings_ to link the framework. Now wondering what directive to use.

Comment: You can still use the directive above to detect if you are building for the simulator.

Comment: I guess I need to define `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` myself right? Is there any pre-defined macro to use?